# How to show and switch between different div id on events

Tags: javascript, html

```
<a id="link1" href="javascript:display('show', 1)">Show</a>

<div id="list1" style="display:none">
VIDEO 1</br>
VIDEO 2</br>
VIDEO 3</br>
</div>
<div id="list2" style="display:none"> 
VIDEO 4</br>
VIDEO 5</br>
VIDEO 6</br>
</div>
```

I want to show List 1 when I click on "Show".

When I click again "Show", it has to show List 2, and List 1 will disappear/hide.

This is the Javascript code which I want to use for it:

```
function display(action, id)
{
    document.getElementById("List"+id).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("link"+id).innerHTML = "MoreVideo";
    action = "freezes";
    document.getElementById("link"+id).onclick=action = "show";

    if(action == "show")
    {
        document.getElementById("List"+id).style.display = "none";
        id = id+ 1;
        document.getElementById("List"+id).style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

That code, will only show List 2... I don't know why.

And yes, I'm very new to Javascript, but I did before PHP, but it looks no way like Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Remove the id parameter:

```
<a id="link1" href="javascript:display('show')">Show</a>
```

```
var id = 2;
function display(action) {
    var div = document.getElementById("List"+id); // Don't 'get' the div that often, save it to a temporary variable.
    div.style.display = "block";
    div.innerHTML = "MoreVideo";
    // action = "freezes"; <-- You're setting `action` to "freezes", preventing the if below from executing
    // div.onclick = action = "show"; <-- That's not valid js

    if(action == "show") {
        div.style.display = "none"; // Hide the current div.
        id = (id === 1)? 2 : 1;      // Set the ID to that of the other div.
        document.getElementById("List"+id).style.display = "block"; // Show the other div.
    }
}
```

So, what's this `id = (id === 1)? 2 : 1;` ?

It's shorthand for:

```
if(id === 1){
    id = 2;
}else{
    id = 1;
}
```

This toggles `id` between `1` and `2`;

Comment: Just to confirm, what Cerbrus within you if statement is make the statement swap between 1 and 2 and not just add 1 to the id each time you click.

Comment: I replace mine code with yours, but the result are the same (it only show List2)

Comment: Will "id = (id === 1)? 2 : 1;" make the code only show List2?

Comment: @OnedZair: What `id` are you passing to your function?

Comment: @Cerbrus id is set to 1 (<a id="link1" href="javascript:display('show', 1)">Show</a>) This right?

Comment: @OnedZair: Ah right. Yea, to show the other one, you'll have to `javascript:display('show', 2)`

Comment: @Cerbrus but how to change the div ID on mouse-click events?

Comment: Oh, you're using that one function to toggle between the 2 divs?

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes that is what I want.

Comment: @OnedZair: Try your browser's JavaScript console. Especially Google Chrome's console is rather good.